# .net OpenFileDialog changing the CurrentDirectory

Tags: c#, .net

I am using `OpenFileDialog`. But using it changes the `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.
Using the `RestoreDirectory` property solves this issue, but I'm using external dlls that I can't control that don't use `RestoreDirectory`.

Is there a way to make it true as default?
Or is there any other solution to this annoying problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you got some sample code to demonstrate the problem? I cannot get the `Enviroment.CurrentDirectory` to change when using `OpenFileDialog` no matter what I try.

Answer (score 2):

Saving the current path and restoring it after the dialog has been shown would do the trick imo:

```
var currentDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

// Show File open dialog etc ...

Environment.CurrentDirectory = currentDir;
```